# start process as administrator in powershell without prompt

Tags: powershell

I startet to look around but only found usage with a prompt. But as this is for the users I was wondering if I can make it run without a prompt still with elevated privileges behind.

```
Start-Process powercfg.cpl -Verb runas
```

this is a simple oneline but this prompts for creds can I somehow tell it just to run elevated without a prompt

Update1: We are thinking of creating a AD User which has only rights for the needed task than can be shared for this prompt.

Update2: WE figured out that pre installed Toshiba software was causing it to jump back after restart and after every edit. We deinstalled the software and since there was no need to run it as admin anymore.

Comment: Just remove the `-Verb runas`. This parameter is used if you want to evelate the rights for this process

Comment: @guiwhatsthat yeah, but I need it to be run elevated as our users have problems with the energy settings and we can't resolve it any other way. But I cant give them the adminstuff so I need to run this without a prompt and evelated prviliges

Comment: The you need to run that comment with an admin account. It's not possible to run a command with evelated rights for a none admin user

Comment: @Kevin - you cannot DO that! [*grin*] you MUST use an account that has the needed privs. if you can't give that info to the person, then you will need to set up a run-once task that uses an account that has the needed privs.

Comment: @kevin, what is the difference between what you said and _"but I need it to be run elevated as my targets have bank details i want to steal and I can't get them any other way"_  It would be a massive security hole if you could easily elevate the rights of a non-admin user.

Comment: I see, i was thinking of giving the credentials within the script maybe as sercure string or something. this would have been packed as .exe within baramundi so it can only be used for this. But still I see its a security problem. Guess need to find another way for our problem.

Comment: If you're in a domain, this kind of problem is usually addressed using Group Policy, which doesn't require handing out rights to users.

Comment: We had a look in the GPO's nothing touches energysettings. But for any reason no user can change them.